# How can I resolve a missing credit card reward check?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

My wife has a points-based rewards card with a significant point balance.  Recently she tried to cash her points (for around $200), requesting a paper check be sent to her mailing address.  After 3 weeks of checking the reward status online and watching the mailbox, the check did not arrive.

I called the issuer's rewards office on her behalf, and they said the check had been sent right after my wife submitted the request.  They recommended that we wait one more week, which we did, but there was still no check.  On calling again, the company said they would cancel the original check and post a new one, and they again recommended waiting 3 weeks.  That period has also now passed, and no check has arrived.

The toll-free number is the only contact the rewards department provides -- no email, no postal address.  My wife wants to file a complaint.  How can we do that?

- [Regions Relationship Rewards VISA card](http://www.regions.com/personal_banking/relationship_rewards.rf)

Comment: Which country do you live in?  What is the name of the credit card company?

Comment: You are seeking to file a "complaint" not to simply "complain". To help with the english.

Comment: We live in USA. I've edited to add the credit card's info, Regions Relationship Rewards VISA card.

Answer (score 1):

If you are determined to file a complaint the correct way to do so is with the bank's regulatory agency.

This probably won't help you get resolution on the refund, but will definitely get the bank's attention and might make you feel vindicated.

[Office of The Comptroller of Currency - File a complaint about a national bank.](http://www.helpwithmybank.gov/complaints/index-file-a-bank-complaint.html)

Here is their [FAQ page](http://www.helpwithmybank.gov/) to guide you through the process.

**Note:** It is possible your bank is regulated instead by the Federal Reserve, but the OCC should be able to re-direct you as needed if your particular bank isn't regulated by them.

In the interest of completeness you can find the regulator for state banks at the [Consumer Financial Protection Bureau](http://www.consumerfinance.gov/askcfpb/1637/how-do-i-find-my-states-bank-regulator.html).